# What is causing this IcecastV2 "Bad or missing password on admin command request" warning?

Tags: icecast

I'm running IcecastV2, and although everything appears to be working - the log file shows this message.

```
INFO admin/admin_handle_request Bad or missing password on admin command request (command: stats.xml)
```

I cannot find a reason that could be causing this?

Edit: Icecast V2.4.4 compiled on Mac.

EDIT:

This is from the error.log file, Followed matched by same time period from access.log

```
    [2019-01-01  13:08:31] INFO admin/admin_handle_request Bad or missing password on admin command request (command: stats.xml)
[2019-01-01  13:08:31] INFO admin/admin_handle_request Bad or missing password on admin command request (command: stats.xml)
[2019-01-01  13:08:31] INFO admin/admin_handle_request Bad or missing password on admin command request (command: stats.xml)
[2019-01-01  13:08:44] INFO format-vorbis/initial_vorbis_page seen initial vorbis header
[2019-01-01  13:08:44] INFO admin/admin_handle_request Received admin command metadata on mount "/live.aac"
[2019-01-01  13:08:44] INFO admin/command_metadata Metadata on mountpoint /live.aac changed to "Kostas Pavlidis - Fake Life"
[2019-01-01  13:08:44] INFO admin/admin_handle_request Received admin command metadata on mount "/live.mp3"
[2019-01-01  13:08:44] INFO admin/command_metadata Metadata on mountpoint /live.mp3 changed to "Kostas Pavlidis - Fake Life"
[2019-01-01  13:09:31] INFO admin/admin_handle_request Bad or missing password on admin command request (command: stats.xml)
[2019-01-01  13:09:31] INFO admin/admin_handle_request Bad or missing password on admin command request (command: stats.xml)
[2019-01-01  13:09:31] INFO admin/admin_handle_request Bad or missing password on admin command request (command: stats.xml)
[2019-01-01  13:10:32] INFO admin/admin_handle_request Bad or missing password on admin command request (command: stats.xml)
[2019-01-01  13:10:32] INFO admin/admin_handle_request Bad or missing password on admin command request (command: stats.xml)
[2019-01-01  13:10:32] INFO admin/admin_handle_request Bad or missing password on admin command request (command: stats.xml)
```

access.log

```
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:08:31 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 360 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:08:31 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 360 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:08:31 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 360 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:08:31 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.0" 200 4439 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:08:31 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.0" 200 4439 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:08:31 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.0" 200 4439 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:08:44 +0000] "GET /admin/metadata HTTP/1.0" 200 396 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:08:44 +0000] "GET /admin/metadata HTTP/1.0" 200 396 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:09:31 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 360 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:09:31 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 360 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:09:31 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 360 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:09:32 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.0" 200 4415 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 1
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:09:32 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.0" 200 4415 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 1
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:09:32 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.0" 200 4415 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 1
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:10:32 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 360 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:10:32 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 360 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:10:32 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 360 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:10:32 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.0" 200 4415 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:10:32 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.0" 200 4415 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:10:32 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.0" 200 4415 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:11:32 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 360 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
192.168.0.7 - - [01/Jan/2019:13:11:32 +0000] "GET /admin/stats.xml HTTP/1.1" 401 360 "-" "sambc/2018.10" 0
```

Comment: Please provide (edit your question) associated and unaltered lines from `access.log` for and around the timestamp of this message. Which version of Icecast is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the combined logs it's pretty obvious what's happening here:

- You are running at least 3 source clients into mountpoints
- The source client each time seems to be `sambc/2018.10` (Possibly SAM Broadcaster?)
- These source clients are making stream metadata update requests via `/admin/metadata`

  - For Ogg that's actually a bug and likely the metadata is broken for listeners.
  - It should embed the metadata inside the stream that it sends to the server instead!
- These source clients are each polling statistics via `/admin/stats.xml`

  - For some reason the source client doesn't cache the fact that authentication is necessary for this URL and follows the 'from zero' HTTP request procedure every time where

    1. first it doesn't send credentials
    2. It gets refused with a HTTP 401 status
    3. It sends the same request again, but including credentials

#### Summarizing: *The behaviour you are concerned about is perfectly within what's defined by the HTTP standards. Icecast is just a bit wordy on that particular event.*

Comment: I'm kind of following what you say. So basically I can ignore these messages as just excessive talk from Icecast. I should change the log level I guess.

Comment: Correct, it's safe to ignore as it just says in this case "I served a 401", which is part of the full authentication process.